# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes after suspend and log files

Tags: 20.04, suspend, log

My Ubuntu 20.04 crashes after I suspend it, but it doesn't happen every time. Sometimes I can keep the laptop on for 7 days suspending and waking it up many times, but sooner or later it'll crash on suspend. It's not a new issue, as it happened before I upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04.

I'm aware of the log files, but I don't know how to read them. I followed some instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545504/ubuntu-crash-how-to-read-log-files) but it never got a full solution. As it happens during suspend time, I am also not sure it would log an error.

I don't think it's a battery issue because when I turn it on again it is always at least half full. I suspect it could be due to the old HDD, but I ran smartmontools short and extended tests and it passed.

Some directions on what log files and what should I look up on them would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you submit it to the software team? That is probably the only thing you can do. You could post your log here, but I don't think anyone will know how to read it either. I hope you fix your problem.